# ActiveAndroid Unable to open database file

Tags: android, database, sqlite, exception, activeandroid

I'm getting an Exception when using Active Android. From what I found on SO this error normally has something to do with not closing the database or transaction. Maybe it has to do with using the database in different threads at once? The Exception only happens randomly what makes me believe it's a strange collision case when I'm updating the database while executing a query at the same time in another thread.

```
unable to open database file
01-20 09:47:32.848    E/SQLiteQuery﹕ exception: unable to open database file (code 14); query
```

Comment: so where is the code that changes db?) i think the code of thread that makes `save` is enough.

Comment: Issue was probably due to using the same db in multiple threads at once, switched to using RealmDB and haven't got any issues since.